# Change search from /?s=searchterm to /searchterm without htaccess in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, search

I'm trying to use the below search form and js to search my site. However, whenever you type a word in the form and click submit the form them takes the users browser to http://example.com/?s=searchterm , but I want it to take them instead to http://example.com/searchterm and totally leave out the characters ?s=

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
    document.forms["searchsite"].submit();
}
</script>
<form id="searchsite" action="/">
<input type='text' name='s' placeholder='search'>
<a href="javascript: submitform()">Submit</a>
</form>
```

Any positive advice? Btw, no, I don't believe I can use htaccess and mod_rewrite since I already have rules set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set an `onsubmit` handler to intercept the form’s submission and replace the default action with setting the location href. This relies on JavaScript being enabled in the client side:

```
<form id="searchsite" action="/" onsubmit="javascript:location.href=this.action + encodeURIComponent(this.elements.namedItem('s').value); return false;">
```

This escapes the search term so that if the user enters something with `?` or `/` in it, the server will interpret that as part of the path instead of thinking that the client is trying to send a querystring or access some subdirectory. The `return false;` states that the browser should stop its normal form submission procedure since the `onsubmit` handler has already updated `location.href`, which will cause the browser to start navigating as soon as the `onsubmit` handler returns.

However, you really should supplement this with server-side code. For something this simple, the JavaScript can be there to make your URIs pretty while skipping an HTTP redirect (so that the browser goes directly to the requested page slightly faster than otherwise). But you should really have a server-side redirect that gets triggered whenever the GET `s` parameter is sent.

Extra note: you should really replace your submission script with a `<button/>`, like:

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

and just drop your `<a/>` and `<script/>` tags completely. You get all of the functionality you need by overriding the form submission handler itself, no need to try to intercept button clicks, etc. With this change, your form should now work when the user presses ENTER instead of requiring the user to TAB to the `<a/>`. Use the intended HTML elements for their intended purposes and hook into the right events ;-).

I assume that your question is only about the client-side of the code and that you already have figured how to get your server-side code to read the value from the URI path. Figuring out how to read the value, if it is submitted this way, would take me some time to research and would require more information about your server-side setup.

Comment: Thank you. THis worked like a champ: <form id="searchsite" action="/" onsubmit="javascript:location.href=this.action + encodeURIComponent(this.elements.namedItem('s').value); return false;">
<input type='text' name='s' placeholder='search'>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

Answer (score 1):

Instead of submitting the form, build the URL and then set the location.  You can add an ID to the search term (`s` in this case) and then simply build the URL:

```
var searchTerm = document.getElementById("s").value;
document.location = "http://example.com/" + searchTerm;
```